# To get the $scope.x1 variable using the another variable in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is an array of the variable names

```
$scope.intialArray =[];
$scope.intialArray[0] ='x1';
$scope.intialArray[1] ='x2';
```

And these values are compututed in controller

```
$scope.x1 = 'somevalue';
$scope.x2 ='another value';
```

Now i want to get the programtically the varialbe names using the intailArray 
Something the below code.

```
$scope.($$scope.intialArray[0].val);
```

Can you please help me with variable evalation in angularjs

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope[$scope.intialArray[0]];
```

try this way :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It worked for me. 
I was finding how to work with array's in angular js in $scope.